# Importing Creatives from Campaign Manager into GCP using Pub Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to import Creatives from Campaign Manager into GCP using Cloud Pub Sub. There are more details on this page https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creative-analysis-at-scale-with-google-cloud-and-machine-learning but it does not give a picture of how to import creatives.

What's the step-by-step process for that ?

Answer (score 1):

That page [suggests storing the creatives in Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creative-analysis-at-scale-with-google-cloud-and-machine-learning#step_2_set_up_cloud_pub_sub_to_automate_the_creative_pipeline). You'll need to upload your creatives into a Cloud Storage bucket. There are a variety of ways to do so (via the Cloud Console, via the `gsutil` tool, or via Cloud Storage REST APIs), discussed [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects).

You could [set up Pub/Sub notifications on your Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications), which you can configure to automatically publish a Pub/Sub message each time a creative is uploaded into your Cloud Storage bucket. Downstream in BigQuery, you can extract the [Cloud Storage URI](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints) from the Pub/Sub message and [feed it into the Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request#providing_the_image).